# jQuery post to the same PHP page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I am creating a jQuery search bar, that will asynchronously send the inputted value from a form from the client side to the same page on the server side (in PHP). Then I can search my database with the value. Unfortunately when I send this value, using $.ajax, and attempt to echo out the value, I don't get the value at all. How can I receive my value? I've tried print_r, var_dump, echo but to no avail.

Here is my form:

```html
<form method = 'POST'>
  <input id="myInput" type ="text"  name ="value" 
  placeholder="press enter when finished" > 
</form>
```

And here is my script to make the call. I get the value in my console when I press enter (key===13), but it seems to be the furthest my variable (value) seems to go.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myInput').bind('keypress', function(e){ 
        if(e.keyCode ===13){
        let value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        console.log(value);
            
        e.preventDefault();  //stops the damn page refreshing
            
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: value
            
        
        });

        };
    });
});
```

I haven't put the URL in the AJAX call for a reason: I'm sending to the same page.

Here is the code (further up the page) that I'm using to echo out the posted value, on the same page.

```php
if(isset($_POST['value'])) { echo $_POST['value']; exit;  }
```

No matter what I seem to do, my value isn't sent to the page! I've tried to add in the URL, I've added "success" to the call.... nothing seems to work.

How can I successfully send my data?

Comment: You never store or use the response from the Ajax callback. So all you're currently doing is making a request in the background but ignore the response. When making an ajax request to fetch data, you need to add a `success` callback to your ajax function that receives the data from PHP and then, using JavaScript, output it where you want it. It won't happen automatically.

Comment: When I add in a response, for example   `success: function () {
                 console.log('success');` I just get another console log, but the data isn't being shown. I don't know if my data is being sent to the server.
                }

Comment: There are literally thousands of examples on how to use jQuery's Ajax function (including the official documentation). You need to add the response as a function argument: `success: function (response) { console.log(response); }`. The variable `response` will contain the response from the server and contains the data you want.

Comment: Oh, you're also sending the data wrong. You're just sending the value "as is" without any key. Add it as a json-object instead: `data: {value: value}`. So, if you would have sent `data: {someKey: 'someValue'}`, then you would fetch the data using `$_POST['someKey']` in PHP.